# docker build fails; cannot resolve ip address

Tags: image, docker, build, ip-address, network-interface

I am trying to create a docker image with a software that requires that an IP address on the host while Docker image doesn't have an IP address during build

Is there a way to have one of the network-interfaces in the image have an IP address at build time so that the software installation can succeed?

It could be any IP address including 127.0.0.1, the installer just checks if there is an IP address.  This is what it checks:
1) the host has an ip address (could be 127.0.0.1)
2) the host has a hostname (which it gets)
3) the hostname can be pinged
4) the 'localhost' can be pinged
5) '127.0.0.1' can be pinged

So far this is what I know of the requirements.

Comment: During build, each step is run in a container which includes its corresponding network interface and IP. Check with `RUN ifconfig`

Comment: Can you expound on this requirement have a specific ip address? What is the ip, and what is the installer doing with it? There is not a way to specify the ip address a container should have during a RUN step during a `docker build`, but depending on the exact requirement the installer has, it might be possible for there to be another workaround.

Comment: @programmerq 
It could be any IP address including 127.0.0.1, the installer just checks if there is and IP address.  This is what it checks:
1) the host has an ip address
2) the host has a hostname (which it gets)
3) the hostname can be pinged
4) the 'localhost' can be pinged
5) '127.0.0.1' can be pinged

So far this is what I know of the requirements.

Comment: @Robert It seems there are many interfaces at the build time but none of them are assigned any ip address

Comment: @programmerq do you have the workaround for me that you mentioned?